# How to get selected index from list in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-places-api

We have a list of places(retrieved from google places API) then they are displayed on google map as markers. Then user can select one place from it and pass to this below function. The problem is I am always only return the first index in the list. What I want is to return selected index of the place selected by the user

```
private fun showInfoWindow(place: Place) {
    // Show in AR
    val matchingPlaceNode = anchorNode?.children?.filter {
        it is PlaceNode
    }?.first {
        val otherPlace = (it as PlaceNode).place ?: return@first false
        return@first otherPlace == place
    } as? PlaceNode
    matchingPlaceNode?.showInfoWindow()

    // Show as marker
    val matchingMarker = markers.firstOrNull {
        val placeTag = (it.tag as? Place) ?: return@firstOrNull false
        return@firstOrNull placeTag == place
    }
    matchingMarker?.showInfoWindow()
}
```

Comment: the argument for this function is single `Place`, are you sure you are passing correct place to this function instead of the first in the list?

Comment: Yeah..  it pass correct place

Comment: is `return@firstOrNull placeTag == place` ever executed? maybe there is some issue with casting here: `it.tag as? Place`?

Answer (score 1):

You're defaulting to *null* for all of these searches, so if you're actually getting non-null results (which are required to call `showInfoWindow`) then that means your `first` predicates are matching something. (Which is a good thing since you're using `first` instead of `firstOrNull` in the earlier part - that will throw an exception if it can't find a match!)

If your predicates are matching the first item in your list, then that suggests that `otherPlace == place` is *true* - they're equal as far as the `equals` method is concerned. If this match is happening when it shouldn't, I'd start by looking there, to see how they're actually being compared.

---

Also, just a couple of useful tips - you can use [`filterIsInstance`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter-is-instance.html) to filter out everything but `PlaceNode`s:

```
val matchingPlaceNode = anchorNode?.children?.filterIsInstance<PlaceNode>()
```

The nice thing about that is the result is a `List<PlaceNode>`, so you don't need to do any casting:

```
val matchingPlaceNode = anchorNode?.children
    ?.filterIsInstance<PlaceNode>()
    ?.first { it.place = place }
```

If you want to cast, like in the second one, you can just do:

```
val matchingMarker = markers.firstOrNull {
    (it.tag as? Place) == place
}
```

Since `place` is non-null, if the cast fails then `null == place` returns *false* anyway. And in this case, you probably don't need to cast at all - you're not doing anything with `it.tag` that requires knowing it's a `Place`, just comparing to `place`. If it doesn't match, it doesn't match! (If there's a possibility they could match even though one is a `Place` and one isn't, then you can do this type checking)

Just some things I wanted to point out, simplifying the code can make it easier to spot where weird things are happening